# DynamicData Remove Sort

Tags: wpf, reactive, dynamic-data

I am using Reactive DynamicData to sort my collections and update the WPF UI. I can apply a sort easy. The problem is how do I get the items to sort back to their original order? What do I send in the DoSort() so it will return to the unsorted original order?

```
    IObservable<IChangeSet<T>> set;
    Subject<IComparer<T>> _sorting;
    Subject<Unit> _resorting;
    ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> _itemset;
    private SortExpressionComparer<T> _currentSort;

    private void DoSort(IComparer<T> sort)
    {
        _sorting?.OnNext(sort);
        //Resort();
    }

    public void Resort()
    {
        _resorting?.OnNext(Unit.Default);
    }

    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> ItemSet()
    {
        if (_itemset is null)
        {
            _sorting = new Subject<IComparer<T>>();
            _resorting = new Subject<Unit>();
            set.Sort(_sorting, resort: _resorting).ObserveOnDispatcher().Bind(out var list).Subscribe();
            _itemset = list;
            DefaultSort();
        }
        return _itemset;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `IChangeSet<T>` that you sort doesn't store the previous ordering of the items somewhere so there is no way to get back the "original" order unless you know how the set was originally sorted and you sort it again using the same `IComparer<T>`.

> What do I send in the DoSort() so it will return to the unsorted original order?

An `IComparer<T>` that sorts the items in the original order basically.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks